# Is there any way where we can call function in javascript only if focus and blur happen with change in input field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input ng-change="onInputChange()" type="text" ng-model="signupForm.name" autocomplete="off"/>
```

I want to call a function only if the input field focused and blurred with changes in input.

Comment: Yes, just keep track of changes, and set what's commonly called a dirty flag.

Answer (score 1):

Normal html5

```
<input type="text" onblur="myFunction()">
<input type="text" onfocus="myFunction()">
```

Angular2+

```
<input type="text" (blur)="myFunction()" (focus)="myFunction()>
```

if you want to call a function only if the value changes, or call a function between specific time, you can use rxjs operator distinctUntilChanged and debouncetime